# Web service in iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap

Hi everyone i am new to iphone development.I am working on an application which required to check and register the user name and password using soap web service.could anyone help me how to do that with that web service.i have two text fields for login.and button to check if the credentials are correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful for you: <strike>http://devmylife.com/?p=111</strike>

<sup>The website disappeared, you can find it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20100704000223/http://devmylife.com/?p=111</sup>

---

## ASIHTTP SOAP Request

First of all down http://www.soapui.org/ or any packet sniffing app. and try requesting your SOAP-service. When you get the SOAP-packet, you have to exactly generate the same packet using ASIHTTP. You have to add headers yourself.

Download latest version of ASIHTTP

```
NSString *urlString = URL_HOST;
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
                             "<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                             "<m:getInboxPosts xmlns:m=\"urn:finditnearwsdl\">"
                             "<input xsi:type=\"tns:InboxPostsRequest\">"
                             "<session_id xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">%@</session_id>"
                             "<page_size xsi:type=\"xsd:int\"></page_size>"
                             "<offset xsi:type=\"xsd:int\"></offset>"
                             "</input>"
                             "</m:getInboxPosts>"
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>" ,adBo.sessionId];
NSLog(soapMessage);
 
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:urlString];
[request appendPostData:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction:" value:SOAP_ACTION];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: thanks buddy but that is the webservice only.i have made that i want to use that to check the user name and password on the screen.could you give me the complete code thanks

Comment: no, i cant. I dont have it. but if u take a closer look at ASIHTTPRequest u'll find authentification.

Comment: thanks dear,now i got that .u can also pass the parameter in the soap body as shown there.i did with different way making a text file containing the soap body and included that in parsing.Well again thanks for helping me bro.See you again helping me if i stuck anywhere in the programming.